# How can I re-highlight a captured regex match in an ace-edit mode?

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I am attempting to highlight all uses of user-defined variables using regex rules.

This is my current rule, which captures a user-defined variable by finding any text with the keyword "var" after it. This custom edit mode is for PBP3, a BASIC compiler for PIC micro-controllers. The regex then looks for any amount of space/new lines and finds any occurrence of the first capturing group, which is the variable name, and then repeats the process.

```
{token : "variable.parameter", regex : /(\w+)(?:\s+var)((?:(.|\n)+)\1*)*/}
```

There are two problems with this, the first one being that the non-capturing groups are somehow being captured and highlighted in the result, and the second being that only a single line seems to be scanned by the regex.

Is there a better way to be doing this?

edit:

This is how the variables are highlighted when they are defined, using the rule:

```
{token : "variable.parameter", regex : /(\w+)(?=\s+var)/}
```

[image: This is how the variables are highlighted when they are defined]

I want every use of these variables to be highlighted in the same color, so something like this would have the text ***mdata***, ***active***, and ***i*** all highlighted orange

[image]

Comment: A non captured Group is still matched, but no Group is created. To match more than once, try setting the 'global' flag.

Comment: This can't work because text is matched line by line, and other rules do not process the text captured by other lines. Could you add an example of code that you want to highlight? there must be other approaches to solve the issue but it is hard to tell without more information.

Comment: I added an example, i tried adding a regex that matches based on where things are in the code, such as `regex : /((\w+)(?=\s+var))|((\w+)?\.?\w+(?=(\[\d\])?\s?=[^=]))/` to highlight all assignments, but this also overrides the highlighting for system variables like _PORTB_